# Will Booting From Flash Drive Format my C: drive? (UBUNTU)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, usb

As the title suggests, when Installing UBUNTU is it possible to JUST install on USB, not onto my whole C: drive?

The reason is is because I want to be able to boot this from any computer (if they are compatible).

So when installing from my Flash Drive, will it install JUST to the USB? Or will it overwrite my computer? (Which I don't want)

Comment: booting from a flash drive, and trying to install to that same flash drive?  or to a different flash drive?  if you're really concerned, and don't plan to do anything with the internal drive anyway, just disconnect it.  you can reconnect it later once you've gotten your installs squared away.

Comment: Yes, I just want to install to that same flash drive. Do you mean COMPLETELY take the hard drive out, then boot?

Comment: I guess that's what @quixotic meant : just unplug the HDD(s) and boot from USB

Comment: Yes, but it is such a hassle (as I am using a laptop), is there any other way?

Comment: no other way guarantees you won't mistakenly tell the installer to touch the internal hard drive in some way.  you could try [adding `libata.force=disable` (or similar)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255888/q-how-to-tell-the-linux-kernel-to-ignore-multiple-ata-devices) to the installer's kernel commandline; if you get it right, the installer shouldn't even see the internal drive.  booting into the live environment and [using tools like `debootstrap` manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/apds04.html) might be a better option.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  If you want to install ubuntu to a flash drive, get a live usb version.